# How to trigger an action on completion/change of a type's property?

Tags: xtext, eclipse-emf

I have the following type in my grammar:

```
TestSuite:
    'TestSuite:' name = ID
    'Type:' type = SuiteType;

enum SuiteType:
    INTERNAL='1' | EXTERNAL='2';
```

I would like to read an xml file whenever the property gets a (new) value since I use the contents of that xml file for validation and content completion. Depending on the value of the property, the xml that will be read will be different.

How would you trigger an action that would read the value of a property of a type from the runtime environment's DSL instance?

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try adding an EMF Adapter to all TestSuite instances such that upon a Notification that changes your 'type' feature to a particular value, the XML file of your choice is read and acted upon.

[this blog post](https://20000frames.blogspot.fr/2010/09/extending-models-in-xtext-projects.html) seems to do the trick: at the end of the linking phase, an Adapter (this is EMF vocabulary, basically a Listener) can be registered for your TestSuite instances.

Then in your Adapter implementation, you can filter whether you need to react using the methods of [Notification](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.3/org/eclipse/emf/common/notify/Notification.html) such as [getFeature()](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.3/org/eclipse/emf/common/notify/Notification.html#getFeature()).

Since you mention you want to do this for content completion and validation, you may need to do all of this in the scoping / validation phases of Xtext. You will probably have a bit of "lag" upon hitting ctrl+space for auto-completion if your IDE needs to find and parse your XML file, but that's to be expected I guess...